# Excel giving cells numbers based on the number in another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, cell

Hope someone could help me out here. I am currently working in an Excel file where I have a cell with a number in there based on an IF formula it gives a number. Now I want let's say you have the number 5 in that cell, I want the cells underneath it to start counting from 1 to 5 (Or the value that's in the cell) but i cant really find a way to figure it out. So i hope you guys can help me

PS: Sorry for my English it's not my native language

Thank you

I tried to search on google but couldn't really find something about this

Comment: Does your version of Excel support the `SEQUENCE` function?

Comment: Mention your excel version and show some sample.

Comment: Thank You BigBen that was the solution! :)